# how to get <select> to display inline?

Tags: css, angular, select, inline

Hi I have a simple label "District" and drop-down with a list of zip-codes. I simply want to have the label and the drop-down to be side-by-side, horizontal on one line but for some reason it will work. It keeps displaying vertically, as in the label on top and menu on bottom.

here is my html:

```
<div class="filterButton leaflet-control">
     <span><i class="fa fa-filter fa-7x"></i>
      <label class="menu">District: </label>
      <select class="ml-1 menuContent" name="zipcode" [(ngModel)]="zipcode" (ngModelChange)="selectedZipcode()">
        <option>-All-</option>
        <option *ngFor="let zipcode of artworkList | duplicates ">{{zipcode}}</option>
      </select>
    </span>
  </div>
```

and my css:

```
.filterButton {
  margin-left: 43px;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 3px;
 }

 .fa-filter:hover  {
   color: #5690C6;
 }

 .fa-filter {
  color: #1770a6;
  font-size: 21px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  align-content: center;
 }

 .menu, .menuContent {
   display: inline;
  }
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or something? https://jsfiddle.net/o6gk7qx3/ It seems to be working on my end with the code you have provided.

Comment: @Elliot Apologies but thank you! The fact that it worked on your fiddle really bothered me, and I just noticed that I had an overlapping property in my global styles file for <select> element.

Comment: do you have a an idea how I could get it animated though? As in, the beginning view I only want to be the icon, and as one hovers on it the menu just slides out on the right side...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make display: inline; or display: inline-block on the filterButton, the wrapper of your elements.

Comment: As @Oly said. Div elements will display as block elements by default. Also, make sure `.ml-1` doesn't have any rules that might counter your styling attempts with the `.menu, .menuContent` selector.